# redirection of awk print to a file

Tags: shell, awk, solaris, csh

I can get the cpu Mhz of a solaris machine by following command.

```
% /usr/sbin/psrinfo -v | grep operate |head -1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

1200

when I run the following command, awk output is not getting redirected.

```
%  csh -cf "/usr/sbin/psrinfo -v | grep operate |head -1 | awk '{print $6}' > myoutput"

% cat myoutput
```

The sparcv9 processor operates at 1200 MHz,

how to get following result

```
% cat myoutput
```

1200

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that `$6` is being evaluated by your existing shell before being passed on to `csh` (and used in the `awk` command).

Escaping the `$` should fix the problem:

```
csh -cf "/usr/sbin/psrinfo -v | grep operate |head -1 | awk '{print \$6}' > myoutput"
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
csh -cf "/usr/sbin/psrinfo -v | awk '/operate/{print \$6; exit}' > myoutput"
```

Comment: Thanks.I have used sed to circumvent the issue.                 "/usr/sbin/psrinfo -v | grep operate |head -1 | sed 's/.*operates at //'|tr -d ','